# Looking for external portable hard disk drive with both Superspeed USB3.0 AND eSATA?

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-3, esata

All I can find is:

- eSATA and USB2.0 *not* USB3.0
- eSATA only
- USB3.0 only
- Enclosure/caddy with USB3.0 and eSATA for housing bare hard drive: http://uk.startech.com/product/SAT2510BU3-25in-SuperSpeed-USB-3-SATA-Hard-Drive-Enclosure (I'd prefer a branded complete product, also I'm not sure if there is any overhead (performance degradation) in converting the internal SATA interface to eSATA).

Why do I want this?

- Versatility - choice of interfaces
- My Toshiba NB100 netbook has eSATA/USB sockets, I may get a USB3.0 ExpressCard for my Apple Mac Book Pro 17" and/or add a USB3.0 PCI card to my Windows desktop. So a hard drive with both USB3.0 and eSATA can be of benefit for high speed transfer on all of these platforms. Sure, some of these platforms may not go to full eSATA or USB3.0 speeds, due to the limits of their external buses and the spindle speed of the external drive being a constraint, but I would expect them to be much faster than USB2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Seagate GoFlex series of hard drives have changeable interfaces.  USB 2.0, USB 3.0, eSATA, Firewire.  Just go to their website.  Of course the caveat is you can only have one interface attached at any given moment, but still, you can only connect to one port anyway.

Comment: +1 I'll accept this answer for now but would prefer both interfaces available on the drive external casing.